# How to replace this SQL query with date ranges by something more Pythonic

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have two pandas data frames:

```
# DataFrame A

  ID      Date      equity
1078604 2000-03-31  145454
1078604 2000-06-30  138536
1078604 2000-09-30  143310
```

The frame above contains >200,000 rows of firms with their IDs and their equity values at quarter end.

```
# DataFrame B

  ID     OtherId  Start       End
1078604     25    1986-06-30  2006-11-04
1049734     94    1986-06-30  1992-10-30
1064894     96    1986-06-30  1990-08-31
```

Frame B contains the same IDs and another identifier (`OtherId`), where `OtherId` is valid for dates from `Start` to `End`.

For a merge I now rely on this `pandasql` statement, which does the trick:

```
import pandasql as ps
def merge_ranges_simple(A, B, sqlcode):
    return(ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals()))

sqlcode = '''SELECT A.ID, A.equity, b.OtherId 
 from A, B 
 where A.ID = B.ID and A.Date >= B.Start and A.Date <= B.End'''

C = merge_ranges_simple(A, B, sqlcode)
```

The resulting frame produces a frame where `ID` and `OtherId` are matched for the proper dates. (I am not too worried about not including the equity value.)

But I wonder, can't python and pandas do the same trick without SQL?

Comment: SQL is awesome - if you can craft a(n) SQL statement to do what you want, why not use it. - To answer your question, yes it can be done without SQL.

Comment: Thanks `wwii`, I get that, but why can't pandas do this, that is, without invoking pandasql?

Comment: [Pandas *can* do it](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).

Comment: @MartienLubberink in your sql statement you have `A.ID = B.ID` but your sample dataframes do not have any results matching that condition. Same for `A.Date <= B.End` as well. All the 'A' dates are > 'B' end dates. Please create a working example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Correctly:

Lets assume the first dataframe(creating a working example by changing the values in ID and the dates a little):

```
>>df

    ID      Date        equity
0   1139710 2000-03-31  145454
1   1139710 2000-06-30  138536
2   1022764 2000-09-30  143310
```

and the second one:

```
>>df1

    ID      OtherId Start       End
0   1139710 21      2000-06-29  2000-06-30
1   1078604 25      1986-06-30  2006-11-04
2   1049734 94      1986-06-30  1992-10-30
3   1064894 96      1986-06-30  1990-08-31
```

using [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df_new=df.merge(df1,on='ID')
>>df_new
    ID      Date        equity  OtherId Start       End
0   1139710 2000-03-31  145454  21      2000-06-29  2000-06-30
1   1139710 2000-06-30  138536  21      2000-06-29  2000-06-30
```

Following this up with your condition using [`pd.series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df_new[df_new.Date.between(df_new.Start,df_new.End)]

    ID      Date        equity  OtherId Start       End
1   1139710 2000-06-30  138536  21      2000-06-29  2000-06-30
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would this work if OtherId was reassigned over time? In other words, suppose firm #1 in your set (1139710) would have OtherId 25 from  2007-03-31 to the present?

Comment: @MartienLubberink that depends on your start and end date filter, but this is how essentially join and a where condition would work in sql, since there was a `>== and <==` i put series.between. If you need any more clarification, i would suggest you to consider placing an expected output dataframe in the question. :)